# Scala cake pattern and multiproject

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

In common-project I have this:

```
trait DBProvider
trait DBTableNamesProvider
trait DefaultDBProvider extends DBProvider
trait DefaultTableNames extends  DBTableNamesProvider

trait MyService extends DBProvider with DBTableNamesProvider

object MyService {
  def apply() = new MyService with DefaultDBProvider with DefaultTableNames {}
}
```

In `projectA` which has a reference to `common-project` as a jar I wish to construct MyService

projectA (has dependency on common-project):

```
object MyOtherApp {
  trait MyOtherTableName extends DBTableNamesProvider
  val MyCustomService = MyService() with MyOtherTableName // will not compile how to reuse the module's MyService() with another implementation of one of the traits?
}
```

The above will not compile I cannot just call MyService() construction and override some of the dependencies.

The above is what I wish to do, I wish to override from a different project the factory construction of MyService() apply with my own implementation of MyProjectATableNames is that possible in scala? if not what is the recommended way without code repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 val MyCustomService = new MyService() with MyOtherTableName
```

should work

If you want to also inherit from the `DefaultDBProvider` and `DefaultTableNames`, you would have to either list them explicitly as well:

```
val MyCustomService = new MyService() with MyOtherTableName with DefaultDBProvider with DefaultTableNames
```

or create an intermediate trait in the common library:

```
trait DefaultService extends MyService with DefaultDBProvider with DefaultTableNames
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override constructed type like that because `MyService()` is an object not a type anymore. So to reuse your code you might create a class like

```
class ConfiguredMyService extends DefaultDBProvider with DefaultTableNames
```

in the first app you can declare

```
object MyService {
  def apply() = new ConfiguredMyService
}
```

and in the second

```
val MyCustomService = new ConfiguredMyService with MyOtherTableName
```

Note: Nowadays, Cake pattern is considered an anti-pattern, so I recommend you checkout Dependency Injection.

Comment: `MyService` is  a trait , and you  certainly CAN extend it anonymously  like that. Also, there is nothing wrong with the cake pattern, except, maybe, for the opinions of a couple of bloggers who happen to like Play.